# Changing dark mode in Material UI theme in a React Context

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm stuck creating a dark mode toggle feature for my web app.  I'm using NextJS with Material UI.
I've tried to create a React context which contains a `useState` and have a switch component change the context.

#### theme.tsx

This is where I define my theme which is fed into the `_app.js` file.

```js
// const { darkMode }: ColorModeContextType = useColorModeContext()
// This line doesn't work since technically `theme.tsx` is outside of the React context I defined.  

const muiTheme: Theme = createTheme()

export const baseTheme: Theme = createTheme({
  palette: { mode: darkMode ? "dark" : "light" },
...
```

#### colorMode.tsx

I define my React context which is used in the `_app.js` file as `<ColorModeContext.Provider>...</ColorModeContext.Provider>`

```js
... 
const ColorModeContext: Context<ColorModeContextType> = createContext({
  darkMode: false,
  setDarkMode: (darkMode: boolean) => {},
})

export const useColorModeContext = () => {
  return useContext(ColorModeContext)
}

interface ColorModeContextProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

export function ColorModeProvider({ children }: ColorModeContextProps) {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const colorModeContext = useMemo(
    () => ({ darkMode, setDarkMode }),
    [darkMode]
  )

  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorModeContext}>
      {children}
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

#### appbar.tsx

Where the user can switch dark mode on or off.

```js
...
const { darkMode, setDarkMode }: ColorModeContextType = useColorModeContext()  
const handleDarkModeSelect = (
    _event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    value: boolean
  ) => {
    setDarkMode(value)
  }

return (
  <CustomDarkModeSwitch
    defaultChecked={false}
    onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, value: boolean) =>
      handleDarkModeSelect(event, value)
    }
)
/>
```

I've tried to fit the example at https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode to my use case but I'm struggling.

My problem in my case is the `theme.jsx` file does not recognize the context so I can't have the context alter the theme.   This is the error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to the ColorModeContext inside the ThemeProvider, I put the ThemeProvider around the ColorModeContext.

```js
export function ColorModeProvider({ children }: ColorModeContextProps) {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const theme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        palette: { mode: darkMode ? "dark" : "light" },
      }),
    [darkMode]
  )

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ColorModeContext.Provider value={{ darkMode, setDarkMode }}>
        {children}
      </ColorModeContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Context.js**

```
 import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

 export const Context = createContext()

 export default function LanguageContext(props) {


const [dark, setdark] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dark')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dark')) : false);


useEffect(() => {
    console.log(language)
}, [])


const changemode = () => {
    if (dark) {
        setdark(false)
        localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(false))
        document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white'
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.backgroundColor = 'white'
        document.getElementById('header').style.backgroundColor = 'white'
        document.getElementById('body').style.color = 'black'

    } else {
        setdark(true)
        localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(true))
        document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundColor = '#23272f'
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.backgroundColor = '#191b21'
        document.getElementById('header').style.backgroundColor = '#191b21'
        document.getElementById('body').style.color = 'white'

    }
}

return (
    <>
        <Context.Provider value={{ changemode, dark }}>
            {props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    </>
)
```

**Header File**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Context } from '../../Context/LanguageContext'
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'

const {  changemode, dark } = useContext(Context)

  return (
    
  <button className="ms-auto" style={{ background: "none", border: "none" }} 
   onClick={changemode}>
            {
                dark ? "" : ""
            }
        </button>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

you're trying to use the useContext hook outside of a component. It's possible that you're importing the theme.tsx file directly in the top-level scope of your application, which would cause the error since useContext can only be used within a component. Try this:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { useColorModeContext } from "./colorMode";

export default function AppWrapper({ children }) {
  const { darkMode } = useColorModeContext();

  const muiTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: darkMode ? "dark" : "light",
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this to the _app.js file but this doesn't change the theme.ts file since the theme.ts is the file outside of the scope of the context.